# How to align sharing buttons a little right?

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the page, the share buttons gets separated from the layout and is to the extreme left. So it looks a little odd.

I want to move the share buttons a little right so that it matches with the alignment of the content layout.

The page i need help with [click here](https://lousysoup.tech/human-cell-atlas/)

Comment: You should provide the code with your question otherwise it will be really difficult to help you.

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the sharing buttons in a P element, just like the blog content. If your browser supports it, you can usually right-click on a part of the page and choose "Inspect" or "Inspect element". From here you can see the layout in action, and see what is different between the two sections.

Inspect Element on Chrome:

[image]

Choosing elements in the inspector to see their styling and layout:

[image]

Notice how the share bar is structurally different (wrapped in a div element with different classes instead of a P element):

[image]

It looks like you need to learn more about CSS, Styles, HTML, and margin/padding if you wanted to solve this on your own.

Comment: Yes, actually! I am a complete newbie in coding.

Well, Thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: Using the Developer Tools in a browser gives you all sorts of power over a website. A website has a modal dialogue you can't get rid of? Inspect Element and start deleting nodes until the modal and its background are gone. Want to get the image from a background? inspect element and look at it's css. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to learn **how to use the devtool** to apply/test the CSS in the browser as **@whiterook6** said.

For your problem, you should add

```
.the_champ_sharing_container.the_champ_horizontal_sharing {
    margin-left: 26%;
}
```

in your css file where `.the_champ_sharing_container.the_champ_horizontal_sharing` is the class of the social sharing div which you can see in the devtool inspect.

Comment: Ya, you are right. 

I needed that piece of code. Thanks for that!